# Getting attachments with token in a map service

Tags: arcgis-server, silverlight

I have successfully built the functionality to load an image stored as an attachment in Silverlight by retrieving the URL of the attachment and binding to it:
(http://Server/ArcGISServer/rest/services/PublishedMap/MapServer/0/3/attachments/4)

However I have implemented token authentication and I was wondering if it's still possible to retrieve the attachment. I can't seem to get it now.

Do I need to embed the token to the URL or something?

(https://Server/ArcGISServer/rest/services/PublishedMap/MapServer/0/3/attachments/4?token=WCQfGMQZ7SmTProN6fX4SZRBr_0pRFDCvYGzkO2I9BlY2vdsKtQRXoHj8pVoFL_izGuLKiBzd3zZlqFv5U767Q..)

Comment: Figured out that i had to enable anonymous access on the arcgisoutput folder :)

Comment: Can you post it as an answer to your question and accept it? That way people will know that the issue has been resolved and also the solution to your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out that i had to enable anonymous access on the arcgisoutput folder

[image]